# IPC in q, how to block until any message is received on handle

Tags: kdb

How to block a control flow until any message is received on handle in 4.0?

In 3.6 version I can use `r:h[]` technique described at https://code.kx.com/q/basics/ipc/#block-queue-flush

But starting from 4.0 the call `r:h[]` hangs forever, even when I'm sending from the second process something like `key[.z.W]@\:".z.i"` (for 3.6 it is the second process kind-of hangs: it starts being a slave of process 1, serving it's only requests, but in 4.0 process 1 hangs forever, answering only to process 2)

This is what I saw in 3.6 2019.04.02:

```
                       │q)\p 15555
q)h:hopen`::15555      │q)
q)                     │q).z.W
q)h[]                  │5|
// blocked             │q)5i".z.i"
".z.i"                 │// blocked
q)q)                   │// blocked
```

Comment: what build of 4.0 are you using? Most likely if there was a bug it will have been fixed in a subsequent build

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the documentation behind that link should read:

*To block until **async** message is received on handle h*

Incoming sync messages on handle h will be processed but will not unblock the socket. The socket will remain blocked until it receives an async message on h

**Server**

```
q)\p 5005                                                                
q)(first key .z.W)".z.i"              
2611i                                 
q)(neg first key .z.W)"myString"
```

**Client**

```
q)h:hopen 5005
q).z.pg:{-1"sync message received";value x}
q)h[]
sync message received

1+1

//socket still blocking

"myString"
q)q)2
q)q)q)q)
```

The 3.6 remote blocking behavior you mentioned was fixed in 3.6_2021.03.04

Comment: Updated documentation. Thanks for the catch! Stephen, KX Librarian